# How does one add custom variable names to an IRF plot?

Tags: r, plot, naming

I have the following code:

```
var <- VAR(data, p=2, type="const", ic="AIC")
names <- 
 c("log(p_l)","log(val)","log(vol)","log(er)",
 "log(lr)","log(Exp)","log(Imp)","log(rgdp)","log(p_oil)","log(r)")

ir_plot <- plot(irf(var, n.ahead=20, ci=0.95, runs=100, seed=123), varnames = names)
```

Where the last argument `varnames = names` is what I am trying to accomplish. I have moved the argument around and tried `variable.names` to no avail. I just want to change the variable names that show up in the plots to the list in `names`.

edit:

One of the plots that the above code gives me is

[image]

I want to change all of the variable names to something more readable. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible by adding `data` as `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `names=` if you want to specify the variable name to be plotted:

```
library(vars)
data(Canada)
var.2c <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "const",ic="AIC")
var_irf <- irf(var.2c, n.ahead=20, ci=0.95, runs=100, seed=123)
plot(var_irf,names="e")
```

[image]

Let's say your would like your new labels on the y-axis to be:

```
newl = paste0("log_",test$response)
newl
[1] "log_e"    "log_prod" "log_rw"   "log_U"
```

Then we create a function that will change the required names but keep your original irf intact:

```
plot_w_names = function(irf,newy){

irf$response = newy
for(i in 1:length(irf$irf)){colnames(irf$irf[[i]]) = newy}
for(i in 1:length(irf$Lower)){colnames(irf$Lower[[i]]) = newy}
for(i in 1:length(irf$Upper)){colnames(irf$Upper[[i]]) = newy}
plot(irf)

}
```

Then run this:

```
plot_w_names(var_irf,newl)
```

[image]

If you want to update everything, try this:

```
plot_w_names = function(irf,newy){
irf$response = newy
irf$impulse = newy
names(irf$irf) = newy
names(irf$Lower) = newy
names(irf$Upper) = newy
for(i in 1:length(irf$irf)){colnames(irf$irf[[i]]) = newy}
for(i in 1:length(irf$Lower)){colnames(irf$Lower[[i]]) = newy}
for(i in 1:length(irf$Upper)){colnames(irf$Upper[[i]]) = newy}
plot(irf)

}
```

Comment: I don't see where `names(var_irf$irf)` falls into my code. Why is the `$irf` there? When I run it I just get a repeated list of what the original variable names are, how do I update it with my list `names`?

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough in my question, I want to change **all** of the variable names in all of the plots. I want to make custom labels for each variable not just show a particular plot. Say I have 3 variables, x_1 x_2 x_3, I want them to show up as "log(1)" "log(2)" "log(3)" in the impulse response plots for x_1 x_2 and x_3

Comment: I updated the post, let me know if there's still ambiguity

Comment: great this works! One thing: How do I make the title update as well? as in your example, it is a shock to log_e not a shock to e